# How can i get the previous data using react query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I am trying to get the previous data using react query, is there any way to get it?

I have a custom hook, it updates every time with new data when I scroll down, But when I get the new data I lost the previous data, so I want to get the previous data

```
const useActivityFeedData = (
  activityFeedPageIndex: number,
  pageSize = Config.defaultPageSize,
) =>
  useQuery(
    [ACTIVITY_FEED, activityFeedPageIndex],
    () => Api.user.getActivityFeedData(activityFeedPageIndex, pageSize),
    {
      initialData: {
        activityList: [],
      },
      keepPreviousData: true,
      select: (res: any) => ({
        activityList: res.activityList,
      }),
    },
  );
```

Comment: You can use the `useInfiniteQuery` for this.  Here is an example that works the same way, when you scroll down it fetches more data.

https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/examples/react/load-more-infinite-scroll